# Laravel Spatie Sitemap only contains 1 URL

Tags: php, laravel, sitemap

I recently setup the sitemap system on my Digital Ocean server. The current issue is that the sitemap only generates for 1 url, that being the main url (example.com).

I was reading through similar issues and saw that it could be that my server isn't allowing the crawler. If that is indeed the issue, what could I do to allow the crawler to run?

Additionally, I haven't made any changes to the default spatie sitemap code. The only thing that was done with the sitemap code, is an artisan command created to have the sitemap run every certain period of time.

Any help on fixing the sitemap issue would be appreciated.